# add_filter before the_content in WP Function

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

I tried add_filter before the_content in function.php But, it displays after the post. I need to display data before post. Actually, filtered content will be the part of my main content. I also tried to add before the_content in single.php, but, it's not looks like any part of my main content. This is the code, I tried.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter', 0 );
    function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
        if (is_single()) {
            global $post;
            $pgLnk=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Button', true);
            ob_start(); 
            ?> 
<!-- Custombodytext --> 
    <p><?php the_field('customtext'); ?></p>
<!-- Custom H2 -->  
    <h2><?php the_field('customh2'); ?></h2>
<!-- Table -->  
        [table id=2 cache_table_output=false /]                                 
    Some contents........   
    <?php 
            $content .= ob_get_clean();
        }
        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: you want to add custom headings and copy to specific pages? Do the headings and copy change from page to page or is it the same?

Comment: Actually, I'm using ACF. In every single post, I added some paragraph, Heading & Tables. So, I have to display all the Custom Field items before my main post. Yah. Heading & paragraph change based on every single post.

Comment: and you want to display before the content? why not edit the template which generates the content, either page.php or single.php or you could create a template and then tell those pages to use that template. Normally the content filter is used to modify the content of the post like the copy of an article ETC.

Comment: I tried to add my custom codes BEFORE the_content & it's displaying perfectly. BUT, when I activate some plugins like social share & advertisements, they displaying AFTER the custom content instead of displaying BEFORE.